# View Tensorboard via Chorme on Windows

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorboard

I used Docker-based installation.

```
$ docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow-full
```

I started Tensorboard like this:

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:6006:6006 -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow-full
python tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir ./ --host 0.0.0.0
```

Then, I opened Chrome. I got TensorBoard on the title, but it was empty.

Here is some pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyiDk.jpg

How to view tensorboard on Docker-based installation correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. 
[View Tensorboard on Docker on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836728/view-tensorboard-on-docker-on-google-cloud)

I used:

`docker run -p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$6006 --name ai-unicorn -t XXXXXXXXXXXX`

(The image number is replaced by X... here)