# How to use TensorBoard in a Docker container (on Windows)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have installed tensorflow on windows through docker toolbox. Everything goes well except I can't use tensorboard. The command line shows 'Starting Tensorboard 29 on port 6006. You can navigate to http://localhost:6006/'.However, when I opened this address on my webbrowser, it just can not connect to it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running TensorBoard inside a Docker container, and trying to use a web browser in Windows to view it, you will need to set up port forwarding from the container to your Windows machine. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838211/3574081) for a longer discussion about port forwarding for TensorBoard, but you should be able to make progress by using the following command:

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:6006:6006 -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

**However,** it may be easier to install TensorFlow directly on Windows, and run TensorBoard there. If you install Python 3.5 for Windows, you can install TensorFlow and TensorBoard by running:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

You can then run TensorBoard directly from the command prompt, and you will not need to worry about port forwarding. See the [Windows installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot!

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to update the answer here, since I just ran into the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and the `latest-gpu` tensorflow docker image (`03e706e09b04`).

What worked for me was the following docker run:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 --rm -v <path_to_logdir>:/logdir tensorflow/tensorflow tensorboard --logdir /logdir --bind_all
```

The server is then accessible at `localhost:6006` as one would expect.
The main difference here is, I guess, adding the `--bind_all` flag to the tensorboard call which exposes the server to external networks, thus allowing the host machine access.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should map your volumes to the folder with the logs and enter with bash well:

```
docker run -v //c/pathto/tf_logs:/tf_logs  
-p 0.0.0.0:6006:6006 -p 8888:8888 -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow bash
cd ..
tensorboard --logdir tf_logs/
```

hit the mapping in your browser

http://192.168.99.100:6006
[image: see your graph]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 + WSL2 + Docker using the offical `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter` image, I had to tell TB to bind to the wildcard address. That is, in the Jupyter notebook, I called:

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/ --host 0.0.0.0
```

After this, I was able to see the embedded dashboard in my notebook.

Comment: Only this answer worked for me, the above answer didn't work for me. Any ideas why ?